# How can I use the auto-generated Id of a record I added in a subsequent task?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, identity, oledbdestination

I am currently adding some records to a table using the `OLE DB Destination`. Each record has an auto-generated `Id` field.
I want to use this generated `Id` field as a foreign key in some child records.

I thought I would be able to a data flow line from one `OLE DB Destination` component to another, but this is not supported.

I would have thought this was a common problem - how do others solve it?

Comment: In T-SQL you can get the value of the identity just generated from `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but that's only if it's on a row by row basis. OLE DB Destination doesn't work row by row. Anyway the way I do this is stage the data into a table and use stored procedures to do it all. What you want probably is possible in SSIS if you use an `OLE DB Command` which does things one row at a time (and is very slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the approach described here:

- [How to insert scope_identity from parent table into the child table using SSIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/96c0788a-4419-496d-b28f-0aa8fa1550f5/how-to-insert-scopeidentity-from-parent-table-into-the-child-table-using-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

In my case it looked a bit like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Benefit
 (PeriodId,
  BenefitCode,
  ...)
VALUES (
  ?,
  ?,
  ...);

SELECT ? = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 3):

## Workarounds

### (1) Generate identity values using Script component

1. Before `DataFlow Task` add an `Execute SQL Task` that return the `MAX(ID)` from this table

   ```
   SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MY_TABLE
   ```
2. Store the result in a Variable *(ex `@[User::MaxID]`)* using a `Single Row` ResultSet
3. In the DataFlow Task Add a Script Component, Mark `@[User::MaxID]` as `ReadOnly` Variable
4. Add an Output Column of type `DT_I4` *(ex: `NewID`)*
5. In the Script Editor use the following Code *(i used Visual Basic language)*

   ```
   Imports System  
   Imports System.Data  
   Imports System.Math  
   Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper  
   Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper  

   <Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute> _  
   <CLSCompliant(False)> _  
   Public Class ScriptMain  
       Inherits UserComponent 

       Private CurrentID as Integer  = 0

       Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()  
           MyBase.PreExecute()  

           CurrentID = Me.Variables.NewID

       End Sub  

       Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)  

           CurrentID += 1

           Row.NewID = CurrentID


       End Sub 

   End Class
   ```
6. In the `OLEDB Destination` check the `Keep identity` option, and Map the `NewID` column to the destination identity column

Then you can use the `NewID` column before that data is imported to OLEDB Destination, because the identity values are predicted in this workaround. *(you can add Multicast component to duplicate the data flow, if you need to perform another operation in parallel)*

**References**

- [How to access ssis package variables inside script component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450289/how-to-access-ssis-package-variables-inside-script-component)
- [Using Variables in the Script Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/data-flow-script-component/using-variables-in-the-script-component)
- [Map Result Sets to Variables in an Execute SQL Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141689(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [SSIS Basics: Using the Execute SQL Task to Generate Result Sets](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/)

---

### (2) Use staging table

1. Create a staging table with an identity column
2. Insert data into staging table
3. Use the staging table in the Data Flow Task

Comment: You always beat me with VB,

Comment: I wrote my answers in VB because it is easier to understand. But i like writing C# code more than VB. :)