# Add incremental number while inserting records using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, identity

I have a SSIS package in which, two records are coming. I need to insert the records in the table with an extra column (let's say Sequence). If there are two records, Sequence column should have the value 1(for the first record) and 2(for the second record). Again, next time, I'm getting three records, then again sequence starts from 1,2 and 3.

Is there anyway to do this **without using script or stored procedure?**

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: `Is there anyway to do this without using script` Why??

Comment: That’s the requirement. If I can use script then it’s easy. But without script or stored procedures, I need to know is there any other approach.

Comment: As i suggested use a staging table

Comment: There is no other solution in SSIS (`Script component`, Staging table and `OLEDB Command` which is not recommended at all because it processes row by row)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334344/how-can-i-use-the-auto-generated-id-of-a-record-i-added-in-a-subsequent-task for more information you will find helpful information in the comments and answers

Comment: One last thing is that the most efficient way is to use a script component (from performance and storage perspectives)

Comment: I don't think that you can use `OLEDB command` in this case, even if it not recommended at all. Only 2 methods (Staging Table and Script Component) or if the source is QSL Table you can use SQL Command with `ROW_NUMBER()` as source to add auto increment field.

Comment: @RanjithVaradan i updated my answer take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 methods to achieve this:

## (1) why not using a script component?

*I think that using script component is more efficient and more controlled, you can write your own logic*

1. In the DataFlow Task Add a Script Component
2. Add an Output Column of type `DT_I4` *(ex: `NewID`)*
3. In the Script Editor use the following Code *(i used Visual Basic language)*

   ```
   Imports System  
   Imports System.Data  
   Imports System.Math  
   Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper  
   Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper  

   <Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute> _  
   <CLSCompliant(False)> _  
   Public Class ScriptMain  
       Inherits UserComponent 

       Private CurrentID as Integer  = 0


       Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)  

           CurrentID += 1

           Row.NewID = CurrentID


       End Sub 

   End Class
   ```
4. In the `OLEDB Destination`,Map the `NewID` column to the destination identity column

## (2) Using Staging Table

*As similar to what i mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334344/how-can-i-use-the-auto-generated-id-of-a-record-i-added-in-a-subsequent-task):*

1. Create a staging table with an identity column
2. Each time Truncate the Table *(this will restart identity)*, and Insert data into staging table
3. Insert data from Staging table using a `DataFlow Task` or an `Execute SQL Task`

Comment: Thanks @Hadi. I'm going with Scripts, business accepts using script component

Comment: @RanjithVaradan this is the better choice, it is more performant and less complex than staging table. You are always welcomed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a staging table with an `IDENTITY(1,1)` column, each time you execute the package you have to `TRUNCATE` the table to reset `IDENTITY`. So each time it will start from `1`

Or you can write your own logic using a Script Component

Comment: I can't find any documentation, but I don't think that Bulk Insert (Fast Load in SSIS) guarantees row order.  To insure row order, be sure to turn off fast load in the destination.  You'll have to weigh out the performance impact of this vs. doing something simple like using a script component as shown in another answer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in the Database itself without the need of adding a Logic in the SSIS package. Just add a Column to your Destination table with IDENTITY and it will be automatically incremented. There is No Need to add Some Additional Logic in SSIS

You Can Add the IDENTITY Column (If you don't have one already on the Table) by Just altering your Table

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD SeqNo INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

IDENTITY(1,1) Mens the Value of SeqNo for the First Record will be 1 and then it will be Incremented by 1 for each record inserted

Comment: Thanks @jayasurya, but the thing is, the sequence should be there for particular records only, not all records. and also, if again, I'm insert three records, it should start from 1, not from the previous number

Comment: So you mean it should reset for each Batch ?

Comment: Yes @Jayasurya.

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh or imagine a line or record number inside a file. You can't do that in the database or using a Sequence

Comment: You could insert the new records into a separate table with an identity column and then insert that table (after casting the Identity column to int or varchar) into the final table. It ain't pretty but it should work?