# FTP task fails due to variable path

Tags: variables, ssis, ftp, etl, script-task

I'm getting the below error when trying to process FTP task,i need using  rename FTP task, it continuously fails when in this step, I'm unsure if the path is correctly defined. In the destination i'm basically calling destination variable + filename + current date but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

> Error: 
>   Failed to lock variable "\\servername\transfer\Reporting\Completed Processing\Daily Report_2019-02-18.xlsx" for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occurs when an attempt is made to retrieve a variable from the Variables collection on a container during execution of the package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".

Comment: Show us how you are attempting to do this. Based on the error, I think you've got your wires crossed somewhere along the way

Comment: Issue is with the incomplete path. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another task in your package is accessing/using the variable at the same time as your FTP task hence why read access is locked.

Solution:

1. You can duplicate the variable and use the duplicated one in your FTP
   task

OR

2. Make sure other tasks that might be using the variable completes before your FTP task begins.

Answer (score 0):

The main error message is:

> Failed to lock variable "\servername\transfer\Reporting\Completed Processing\Daily Report_2019-02-18.xlsx" for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found.

This error shows that you are passing the following value `\\servername\transfer\Reporting\Completed Processing\Daily Report_2019-02-18.xlsx` as a variable name which is nopt adequate.

You can refer to the following links for learning more on how to use variables inside a script task:

- [Use SSIS Variables and Parameters in a Script Task](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22194.use-ssis-variables-and-parameters-in-a-script-task.aspx)
- [Using Variables in the Script Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/using-variables-in-the-script-task?view=sql-server-2017)
- [How to access ssis package variables inside script component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450289/how-to-access-ssis-package-variables-inside-script-component)